# Can I use any nonce as long as it is not previously been used?

Tags: transactions, nonce, raw-transaction

When creating raw transactions, do I have to increase the nonce always in increments of 1 or can I use any nonce as long as it has not been used before?

Are there any specific rules? Could I also go up and down, like transaction #5 gets nonce 17 and transaction #6 gets nonce 13?

Can I use any nonce as long as it is not previously been used?

Comment: Increase by one or your tx queue is filled, AFAIK but I am on the phone...there is an answer explaining this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the nonce needs to equal the number of transactions sent from the address; so that also means no jumping around.

> The account state comprises the following four fields: nonce: A scalar
>   value equal to the number of transactions sent from this address

(Section 4.1 of Yellow Paper)

Comment: Strictly monotonic increasing starting from 0.

Comment: On practice it seems that if you skip a number in nonces of your transactions they will never be taken from the mempool, waiting indefinitely for that skipped number. So, yeah, **strictly monotonic increasing**.

Comment: @Klesun Yes. The transactions skipping a nonce are not valid transactions yet, so that's why no one will put them in a block, because doing so would make the block invalid, and no one would build on top of an invalid block. You probably see that once there's a transaction with the missing nonce, that transaction and others with subsequent nonce, could have a chance of all getting included into the same block.