# Problem after withdrawal non hard fork ethereum

Tags: hardforks, replay-attack, ethereum-classic

I have a problem, I successfully withdraw some ETC but when I tried another time to withdraw the rest I think I put in more ETC and I didn't receive anything and now when I try again to withdraw any amount it won't work, not even with 1 ETC. In mist appears like the transaction was successful but the coin never reached the exchange. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you are sending your transactions from the hard-forked ETH chain, and your transactions are being replayed on the non-hard-forked ETC chain.

If this is the case, your problem is most likely due to the error transaction on the ETC chain causing the transaction nonce (see [1](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6899/can-i-use-any-nonce-as-long-as-it-is-not-previously-been-used) and [2](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2808/what-happens-when-a-transaction-nonce-is-too-high)) to be out of sync between the two chains.

Subsequent transactions sent from the ETH chain would have the transaction nonce out of sequence and would therefore fail.

Here is an example:

```
Transaction ETH Nonce ETH Chain Status ETC Chain Status
----------- --------- ---------------- ---------------------------------
1           1         Success          Success              
2           2         Success          Success        
3           3         Success          Error Tx Value > Account Balance
4           4         Success          Error, expecting nonce #3
5           5         Success          Error, expecting nonce #3
```

If you want to execute a transaction on the ETC chain, you will have to start a node on the ETC chain and send your transaction from this node. The correct nonce will be used by your wallet software.

I've just set up a separate computer for to keep the ETH and ETC chain data separate. And use a [conditional contract](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/how-to-conditionally-send-ethers-to-another-account-post-hard-fork-to-protect-yo) to make sure that your replayed transactions don't end up unexpectedly transferring amounts into incorrect accounts on the other chain.